# Confused with list append in Python

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

```
a=[10, 23, 56, [78]]
b=list(a)
a[3][0]=95
a[1]=34
print(b)

# why is the out this [10, 23, 56, [95]] and not this [10, 34, 56, [95]]
>>[10, 23, 56, [95]]
```

I know how the append works I guess but I am not able to comprehend this one or may be my knowledge for append is too shallow

Comment: b is a shallow copy of a. That meaning that integers in this example are copied, but only references to nested objects are. That's why only the subarray of b is updated. [Doc on deep and shallow copy.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Answer (score 1):

The list *a* contains 3 ints and a list.

After `b=list(a)`, `b` is a list (obviously) with copies of the ints and `a` reference to the original sub-list at index 3.

Therefore:

```
a[1] = 34
```

... has no effect on *b*

Whereas:

```
a[3][0] = 95
```

... modifies the list at a[3] and b[3]. Remember, they are the same thing. You could prove this by:

```
assert id(a[3]) == id(b[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was that you defined list b before you edited your list a (why it only indicated half? No idea, python can be a bit weird sometimes :-])

So... as long as you only define your list b after your modifications it should work.

```
#User set list
a=[10, 23, 56, [78]]

#Changing the list
a[1]=34
a[3][0]=95

#Puts a inside of a list named "b"
b=list(a)
print(list(b))
```